# Local and Remote EJB

Tags: ejb

I want to have Local and Remote interfaces of an EJB in same JVM(Weblogic server instance) Is it possible and how can I achieve it.
calling Local EJB is performance benefit as call-by-reference is used.

If possible how it can be defined in deployment descriptor(ej-jar.xml,  weblogic-ejb-jar.xml

Answer (score 0):

You can have both interface of course, the client will use either `@Remote` or `@Local` depending on where it is located if local or remote.

But the point is, as you have already pointed out, the two interfaces serve a completely different purpose.

In theory a remote interface is supposed to be coarse grained, while a local interface fine grained. This 'graining' is driven by how objects are passed within JVM or between JVMs, and because of network issues.

To simplify (a lot), tipically with `@Remote` interface you pass the id and reconstruct the object in the business layer, while using `@Local` allow you to pass the entire object as a reference.

So, if you implement both, expect/design your bean to have different sets of methods serving specific purpose.